# alphabetically sorted if statement not working

Tags: python, mutators

The if statement below has a problem in it somewhere and I can not figure it out. Any conventions or method misuses that might be causing it to not function right? checkList is a user inputed sentence and lis is a large list of words.

```
def realCheck(checkList):  
        string = "".join(checkList)  
    print string  
    wordList = string.split()  
    if match(wordList, lis).sort(key=str.lower) == wordList.sort(key=str.lower):  
        return True  
    else:  
        return False
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If checkList is a string, then there
   is no need for `"".join(checkList)`.
   It just gives you back the same
   string:

   ```
   In [94]: checkList="This is a sentence"    
   In [95]: "".join(checkList)
   Out[95]: 'This is a sentence'
   ```
2. The first line, `string =
   "".join(checkList)` has the wrong
   indentation. Move it back to be
   flush with the other lines in the
   definition.
3. Don't name a variable `string`. It
   overrides the standard Python module
   of the same name.
4. Presumably `match(wordList, lis)`
   returns a list. The sort method
   sorts the list, and returns `None`.
   Since `None == None` is `True`,

   ```
   if match(wordList, lis).sort(key=str.lower) ==  wordList.sort(key=str.lower):
   ```

   is always true.

   More likely, what you want is

   ```
   sorted(astr.lower() for astr in match(wordList, lis))==sorted(astr.lower() for astr in wordList)
   ```

   Unlike the `sort` method, the
   [sorted](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) function returns the
   sorted list.

   As [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847934/alphabetically-sorted-if-statement-not-working/3847938#3847938) points out,

   ```
   sorted(match(wordList, lis),key=str.lower)==sorted(wordList,key=str.lower)
   ```

   always has the same truth value as

   ```
   sorted(match(wordList, lis))==sorted(wordList)
   ```

   So using `str.lower` as the `key`
   for sorting (rather than as a
   transformation before comparing with
   `==`) is probably not what you want.
5. The statement

   ```
   if condition:
       return True
   else:
       return False
   ```

   can be simplified to

   ```
   return condition
   ```

Answer (score 4):

`.sort`, like just about every other mutator method of containers, returns `None`.  So comparing `a.sort()` to `b.sort()` is absurd because they'll both be `None`!  I think you want to compare `sorted(match(wordList, lis), key=str.lower)` with `sorted(worldList, key=str.lower)`.

Note that the `key` is actually irrelevant the way you're using it: if the two lists have items that differ in case, they will **not** compare equal even if they're sorted "comparably"!

So a better idea might be to compare `sorted(s.lower() for s in match(wordList, lis))` with `sorted(s.lower() for s in worList)`.  Note that the `key=` is unneeded here since you're comparing the **lowercased** items so they'll sort that way "by nature".